# Angular 9 Material mat-select layout not formatting correctly

Tags: angular, angular-material

I have the following code:

```
<mat-form-field id="citydropdown"  >
<mat-select placeholder="Office" class="useroptions" name="office"  [(value)]="cityid" >
<mat-option [value]="">Firm-wide</mat-option>
<mat-option [value]="4" >Century City</mat-option>
<mat-option [value]="1" >Los Angeles</mat-option>
<mat-option [value]="2" >Orange County</mat-option>
<mat-option [value]="3" >San Diego</mat-option>
<mat-option [value]="5" >San Francisco</mat-option>
</mat-select>
</mat-form-field>
```

which works using Angular/cli 7.2.3 @angular/material 7.2.3
[image: What the code looks like in my browser for Angular/cli 7]

after I upgraded Angular/cli to 9.1.8 - @angular/material 9.1.3 the layout no longer works 
[image: What the code looks like in my browser for Angular/cli 9]

The Angular 7 version changes the fiellds to div's with css classes to create the layout. In Angular 9, this is not the case.

I have tried installing earlier and later versions of @angular/material - to no avail.

Here is the package.json dependancies for the working version:

```
"dependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/architect": "^0.13.9",
    "@angular-devkit/core": "^7.3.9",
    "@angular-devkit/schematics": "^7.3.9",
    "@angular/animations": "^7.2.16",
    "@angular/cdk": "^7.3.7",
    "@angular/common": "^7.2.16",
    "@angular/compiler": "^7.2.16",
    "@angular/core": "^7.2.16",
    "@angular/forms": "^7.2.16",
    "@angular/http": "^7.2.16",
    "@angular/material": "^7.3.7",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^7.2.16",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^7.2.16",
    "@angular/platform-server": "^7.2.16",
    "@angular/router": "^7.2.16",
    "@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap": "^4.0.2",
    "angular-in-memory-web-api": "^0.6.1",
    "angular-include-replace": "^1.0.0",
    "angular-inline-svg": "0.0.782",
    "angular-svg": "^2.0.8",
    "bootstrap": "^4.3.1",
    "classlist.js": "^1.1.20150312",
    "core-js": "^2.6.3",
    "express": "^4.16.4",
    "hammerjs": "^2.0.8",
    "jquery": "^3.4.1",
    "ng-inline-svg": "^8.3.0",
    "ngx-bootstrap": "^3.2.0",
    "ngx-pagination": "^3.2.1",
    "only": "0.0.2",
    "package-lock-only": "0.0.4",
    "package-lock.json": "^1.0.0",
    "popper.js": "^1.14.3",
    "rxjs": "^6.3.3",
    "rxjs-compat": "^6.4.0",
    "svg.js": "^2.7.1",
    "tslib": "^1.9.3",
    "web-animations-js": "^2.3.1",
    "zone.js": "^0.8.29"
  },
```

Here is the package.json for the one that isn't working

```
"dependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/architect": "^0.901.8",
    "@angular-devkit/core": "^9.1.8",
    "@angular-devkit/schematics": "^9.1.8",
    "@angular/animations": "^9.1.11",
    "@angular/cdk": "^9.2.4",
    "@angular/cli": "^9.1.8",
    "@angular/common": "^9.1.11",
    "@angular/compiler": "^9.1.11",
    "@angular/core": "^9.1.11",
    "@angular/forms": "^9.1.11",
    "@angular/http": "^7.2.16",
    "@angular/material": "^9.1.3",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^9.1.11",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^9.1.11",
    "@angular/platform-server": "^9.1.11",
    "@angular/router": "^9.1.11",
    "@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap": "^6.1.0",
    "angular-in-memory-web-api": "^0.11.0",
    "angular-include-replace": "^1.0.0",
    "angular-inline-svg": "0.0.911",
    "angular-svg": "^2.0.8",
    "bootstrap": "^4.5.0",
    "classlist.js": "^1.1.20150312",
    "core-js": "^3.6.5",
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    "hammerjs": "^2.0.8",
    "jquery": "^3.5.1",
    "ng-inline-svg": "^10.1.0",
    "ngx-bootstrap": "^5.6.1",
    "ngx-pagination": "^5.0.0",
    "popper.js": "^1.16.1",
    "rxjs": "^6.5.5",
    "rxjs-compat": "^6.5.5",
    "svg.js": "^2.7.1",
    "tslib": "^2.0.0",
    "typescript": "^3.7.5",
    "web-animations-js": "^2.3.2",
    "webpack": "^4.43.0",
    "zone.js": "^0.10.3"
  },
```

Answer (score 0):

I need to make the following changes to the app.module.ts file

from:

```
import { MatButtonModule, MatCheckboxModule, MatSelectModule, MatTabsModule, MatRadioModule, MatMenuModule, MatTooltipModule } from '@angular/material';
```

to:

```
import { MatFormFieldModule } from '@angular/material/form-field';
import { MatSelectModule } from '@angular/material/select';
import { MatButtonModule } from '@angular/material/button';
import { MatCheckboxModule } from '@angular/material/checkbox'; 
import { MatRadioModule } from '@angular/material/radio';
import { MatMenuModule } from '@angular/material/menu';
import { MatTooltipModule } from '@angular/material/tooltip';
```

Answer (score 0):

Try doing this for displaying your options:

**Html tags:**

> ```
> <mat-select>
>  <mat-option *ngFor="let city of cities" [value]="option.value">
>   {{option.viewValue}}
>  </mat-option>   
> </mat-select>
> ```

**Typescript Interface**

> ```
> interface City 
> {   
>    value: string;  
>    viewValue: string; 
> }
>
> @Component({   
>     selector: 'your-component',   
>     templateUrl: 'your-component.html',   
>     styleUrls: ['your-component.css'], }) 
> export class YourComponent {   
>     cities: City[] = [
>     {value: 'lasvegas-0', viewValue: 'Las Vegas'},
>     {value: 'chicago-1', viewValue: 'Chicago'},
>     {value: 'columbus-2', viewValue: 'Columbus'}   
>    ];
> }
> ```